# Knot Resolver: Paralelism and concurrency in modules

Tags: dns

## Context

Dear Knot Resolver users, I have a [module that hooks into Knot's](https://github.com/Karm/knot-sinkit/blob/master/modules/sinkit/sinkit.c#L213-L215) `finish` phase,

```
 static knot_layer_api_t _layer = {
     .finish = &collect,
 };
```

the purpose of the collect function `static int collect(knot_layer_t *ctx) {` is to ask an external oraculum via a REST API whether a particular domain is listed for containing a malware or phishing campaign and whether it should be resolved or sinkholed.

It works well as long as Knot Resolver is not targeted with hundreds of  concurrent DNS requests.
When that happens, given the fact that the oraculum's API response time varies and could be as long as tens to hundreds of milliseconds on occasion,
clients start to temporarily perceive very long response times from Knot Resolver, far exceeding the hard timeout set on communication to oraculum's API.

## Possible problem

I think that the [scaling-with-processes](https://knot-resolver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/daemon.html#scaling-out) actually
renders the module very inefficiently implemented, because queries are being queued and processed by
module one by one (in a particular process). That means if `n` queries almost-hit oraculum's API timeout limit `t`, the client
who sent its `n+1` query to this particular kresd process, will perceive a very long response time of accumulated `n*t`.

Or would it? Am I completely off?

When I prototyped similar functionality in GoDNS using goroutines, GoDNS server (at the cost of hideous CPU usage) let numerous
DNS clients' queries talk to the oraculum and return to clients "concurrently".

## Question

- Is it O.K. to use Apache Portable Runtime threading or OpenMP threading and to start hiding the API's response time in the module? Isn't it a complete Knot Resolver antipattern?
- I'm caching oraculum's API responses in a simple in memory ephemeral LRU cache that resides in each kresd process. Would it be possible to use kresd's own MVCC cache instead for my arbitrary structure?
- Is it possible that the problem is elsewhere, for instance, that Knot Resolver doesn't expect any blocking delay in `finish` layer and thus some network queue is filled and subsequent DNS queries are rejected and/or intolerably delayed?

Thanks for pointers (pun intended)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Knot Resolver developer here :-) (I also repeat some things answered by Jan already.)

- Scaling-with-processes is able to work fine. Waiting for responses from name-servers is done by libuv (via event-loop and callbacks, all within a single thread).
- Due to the single-threaded style, no layer function should be blocked (on I/O), as that would make everything block on it. AFAIK currently the only case when this can really happen is when (part of) the cache gets swapped-out.
- There is the YIELD state http://knot-resolver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lib.html?highlight=yield It's used when a sub-request is needed before processing of the layer can continue, but I currently don't know details of its working.  I don't think it's directly applicable, as resuming the layers seems currently only triggered by a sub-request finishing.
- Cache: if you put your module before the rrcache module and you change the RRset, it will get cached changed already.

Answer (score 1):

Knot DNS developer here (not Resolver though). I think you are right. My understanding is that the layer code is executed synchronously in the daemon thread. The asynchrony appears only at the resolver network I/O level.

Internally the server runs libuv loop which just executes callbacks for events on primitives provided by libuv (sockets, timers, signals, etc.). The problem is that you just cannot suspend the running callback (C function) at an arbitrary point, escape back to libuv loop, and continue with the callback execution at some point later.

That said, asynchronous waiting for an event can happen only where this was expected. And the code driving layers doesn't expect that.

**Answers:**

- I'm not very familiar with libapr or OpenMP. But I don't think this could be really solved without reworking the layer interface and making it asynchronous.
- The shared cache could be used for sure. If you cannot find the API, jolly Knot DNS folks will happily accept a patch or help you writing one.
- This is exactly the case. Knot Resolver doesn't expect blocking code in the layer finish callback.